# How to apply imgix-js on command?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, imgix-js, imgix

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var imgixOptions = {
        updateOnResizeDown : true,
        updateOnPinchZoom : true,
        fitImgTagToContainerWidth: true,
        fitImgTagToContainerHeight: true,
        autoInsertCSSBestPractices: true,
        pixelStep : 5
    };

    imgix.onready(function() {
        imgix.fluid(imgixOptions);
    });
});
```

---

This works as expected on dom ready however some pieces of my site load dynamically using AJAX.

How can I trigger the imgix-js library to load the images the way it does on dom ready?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to call `imgix.fluid` on the new content after the AJAX load completes, passing in the parent node of the new content to limit the scope of the new `.fluid` call. Something like this:

```
// Store the target that your async content is being inserted into
var $target = $('#target');

// Make your AJAX request
$target.load('new_content.html', function () {
  var imgixOptions = {
    updateOnResizeDown : true,
    updateOnPinchZoom : true,
    fitImgTagToContainerWidth: true,
    fitImgTagToContainerHeight: true,
    autoInsertCSSBestPractices: true,
    pixelStep : 5
  };

  // Call imgix.fluid, passing the target as the rootnode.
  // Note that imgix.fluid expects the rootnode to be an HTMLElement
  // rather than a jQuery collection, so call .get(0) on $target
  imgix.fluid($target.get(0), imgixOptions);
});
```

I totally recognize that this isn't very intuitive at the moment--you've already called `imgix.fluid()` at the document level earlier, so marking these new images as fluid independently doesn't smell quite right. We're aware of this limitation and will figure out a way to make this work better in a future version of the library. If you've got specific ideas on how you think this behavior should be handled, you should email me at jason@imgix.com and I'd be happy to discuss!

Answer (score -1):

```
/* imgix parameters */
var watermarkParams = {
      w: 320,
      h: 320,
      fit: 'crop',
      q: 90,
      auto: 'format',
      mark: '/imgix-logo-web.png',
      markalign: 'center,middle',
      markw: 160,
      markalpha: 80,
      markpad: 20
};

/* Construct imgix URL */
var watermarkImage = new imgix.URL('https://assets.imgix.net/examples/mountain.jpg');
watermarkImage.setParams(watermarkParams);
watermarkImage.attachImageTo('#image-example');
```

Comment: I didn't downvote Miguel, however I'm not sure how this applies to my current problem. Are you saying I need to run `attachImageTo` to all my images everytime I need to re-run the imgix-js optimizer?